# Not getting params from JSON API POST Request in Rails 4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4, http-post

I'm doing a login function for the API of a Web app in Rails 4.
The idea is to be able to login from an Android app sending a JSON with a username and password_digest.

This is my api_controller:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
#respond_to :json
before_filter :restrict_access, except: :login
protect_from_forgery except: [:login, :new_ticket]

##==========================================================================
# /api/login/:username/:password_digest
##==========================================================================
def login
    @user = User.find_by_username(login_params[:username])

    if not @user
        user_not_found = 'No existe este usuario'
        render json: {error: true, message: user_not_found}, status: 404
        return
    elsif  not @user.authenticate(login_params[:password_digest]) 
        wrong_password = 'Contraseña incorrecta'
        render json: {error: true, message: wrong_password}, status: 400
    else
        access_token = @user.api_key.access_token
        render json: {access_token: access_token, authenticated: true}
    end
end

##==========================================================================
# /api/users/:access_token/
##==========================================================================

def users
    @users = User.all
    render json: (@users.map { |u| u.as_json(except: :password) }).to_json
end

private
def restrict_access
    api_key = ApiKey.find_by_access_token(params[:access_token])
    head :unauthorized unless api_key
end

def login_params
    params.permit(:username, :password_digest)
end


end
```

I'm making a POST request with the username and password_digest but I'm getting {} in login_params. Why? Thanks!

Edit: And this is the definition of my routes

```
scope 'api' do
  post '/login', to: 'api#login'
  get '/users/:access_token', to: 'api#users'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, parameters are working when using curl but not with "Advanced rest client" chrome plugin